# php5apache2_4.dll The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, apache

My `httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

I have Windows 7 32-bit. I downloaded `Apache 2.4.12 Win32` from http://www.apachelounge.com and I downloaded `PHP 5.6 (5.6.10) VC11 x86 Thread Safe` from http://windows.php.net

I have installed `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC`

Comment: This happened to me after an update. I had to repair "Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64/86)" under Programs and Features in windows10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4` and it worked perfectly.